# Trying to pull data from MYSQL with Debezium gives error

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have been trying to pull data out of MYSQL bin logs for CDC with Debezium. I tried it with the tutorial they provided [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html) and it works fine. But When I setup kafka and mysql and other dependenices on standalone mode rather than in docker it isn't working.I tried to get the error with the url:

`/connector-plugins/source/config/validate`.
But the error received is

````
"error_code": 400,
    "message": "Included connector type io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector does not match request type source"```. When the POST API is used error is given as
````

"error_code": 400,
"message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nUnable to connect: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"

The config file used is

```
{
  "name": "inventory-connector",  
  "config": {  
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",  
    "database.hostname": "mysql",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "root",
    "database.password": "password",
    "database.server.id": "1",  
    "database.server.name": "server",  
    "database.include.list": "test", 
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",  
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "sample"  
  }
}
```

There are two parts to this problem Iam not undestanding.

1. Why is the first error occurs at `/connector-plugins/source/config/validate`, because what I understood is debezium is source connector?
2. What could be the issue of this configuration failing while trying to create the connector?

Comment: When you say "standalone mode", this is outside of Docker, so how are you resolving the database hostname?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am running the database outside docker in the Xampp. I have tried hostname as localhost as still doesnt work.

Comment: Should work if Debezium is running on the same host and you've enabled mysql binlogs

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Iam able to get ti to work now. But only DDL commands are being pulled. No DML inforamtion such as create , update or delete is being fetched. What could be the problem? It just gives an event in kafka topic showing ddl" : "# Dummy event replacing even"

Comment: I assume that's controlled by some mysql configuration... I've personally never used Debezium

Comment: @pacman How did you get this to work? I'm facing the same issue.